# How to make a copy of a docker image

Tags: docker

I currently have docker image which is like this

```
docker.foo.com/ua/my_img:latest
```

I would like to make a clone of that at another repository

```
docker.foo.com/ub/my_cloned_img:latest
```

Is there any docker command that can let me duplicate the content from one address to another ?

Comment: Have you tried to docker pull, tag, and push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pull that docker image to your local, then tag it with another name and push:

```
docker pull docker.foo.com/ua/my_img:latest
docker tag docker.foo.com/ua/my_img:latest docker.foo.com/ub/my_cloned_img:latest
docker push docker.foo.com/ub/my_cloned_img:latest
```